# Override scopes in syntax definitions?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I'm trying to write a [mustache](https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html) syntax definition for Sublime Text 3, but I'm running into problems with HTML tag scope.

Any mustache variables or sections work fine outside of an html tag, but if they're inside, they are styled according to the scope of the tag.

For example:

```
{{var}}
{{#block}}
    <div {{#enabled}}class="enabled"{{/enabled}} id="{{id}}"></div>
{{/block}}
```

`var` and `block` will be highlighted properly, but `enabled` will be highlighted as if it were an attribute, and `id` as a string.

Is there a way to make the mustache variables and sections take precedence over the HTML tags?

Here is the YAML for my syntax definition:

```
patterns:
- include: text.html.basic

- name: comment.block.mustache
  match: '\{\{!(.*?)\}\}'

- name: markup.mustache
  begin: '\{\{[&>#^] *(.*?) *\}\}'
  beginCaptures:
    '1': {name: entity.name.tag.mustache}
  end: '\{\{\/ *(\1) *\}\}'
  endCaptures:
    '1': {name: entity.name.tag.mustache}
  patterns:
  - include: $self
  - include: text.html.basic
    match: '[\s\S]'

- name: variable.mustache
  begin: '\{\{\{?'
  end: '\}?\}\}'
  captures:
    '0': {name: entity.name.tag.mustache}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know how to do this with the old YAML syntax definitions. However since you use ST3 you can use the new `.sublime-syntax` files (explained [here](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/syntax.html)). With these you can define prototypes when "pushing" other syntax definitions.
In this definition you include an other syntax by writing `push "Packages/path/to/file.sublime-syntax"`. Afterwards you can add prototypes, which will be matched inside the syntax.

I made an syntax definition, which should have the behavior you wanted:

```yaml
%YAML 1.2
---
name: Mustache
file_extensions: ["mustache"]
scope: text.html.mustache

contexts:
  main:
    - match: ""
      push: "Packages/HTML/HTML.sublime-syntax"
      with_prototype:
        - include: unescape
        - include: comment
        - include: block

  unescape:
    - match: "{{{"
      push: "Packages/HTML/HTML.sublime-syntax"
      with_prototype:
        - match: "}}}"
          pop: true

  comment:
    - match: '{{!(.*?)}}'
      scope: comment.block.mustache

  block:
    - match: "{{"
      scope: meta.block.begin.mustache
      push:
      - match: "}}"
        pop: true
        scope: meta.block.end.mustache
      - include: sections
      - include: variable

  sections:
    - match: "(#|^)(\\w+)\\b"
      captures:
        2: entity.name.tag.mustache
      scope: meta.block.section.start.mustache
    - match: "(/)(\\w+)\\b"
      captures:
        2: entity.name.tag.mustache
      scope: meta.block.section.end.mustache

  variable:
    - match: "\\b\\w+\\b"
      scope: entity.name.tag.mustache
```